# Swiftmailer Slow Because of waiting for server response/blocking

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer

Our hosting company's email servers often get slow, and emails can often arrive minutes or even hours late.   In order to combat this, we've installed Swiftmailer (SMTP to Google) to send out emails that must be received immediately.

The problem with this is, sending an email through Swiftmailer takes A LOT longer (~0.5s vs 3 seconds).  As such we've held out on rolling out Swiftmailer on anything customer facing.  But we're at the point where that's no longer an option, so we need to somehow use Swiftmailer to send out the emails, but not block/wait for a response from Google's SMTP somehow (I believe that is the culprit).  Even if that means not getting a reliable 'sent' return value.

Any one have any idea how this might be accomplished?

Comment: If you want to send an email to gmail smtp, you can use PHPMailer library. and if you want to return to user without waiting for the response from gmail, add info to a db and send email using a cron job in backgroud

Comment: @Ima That sort of defeats the purpose of why we're using Swiftmailer though, we use it because we need it to be instant (and not wait for a cron to execute).  For everything that isn't time sensitive we just the server's internal server.

Comment: This can be more than instantaneous based on interval of your cron(The interval of cron can be 1 perr minute). Only difference is this wont block the user request